# How can I monitor pg_notify data?

Tags: postgresql, pg-notify

I am handling the application which use pg_notify to capture any data based on event insert, update, and delete. The problem is some of data were not synced properly. Now with this regard, I would like to monitor every single data notified by pg_notify function to ensure that it is successfully sent to client/subscriber who listen. The reason is I would like to point out the failure point is not caused by pg_notify which means it is the application who can't process the data accordingly or some other factors. Is it possible to do the monitoring ?

Comment: If you are concerned about lost messages, then pg_notify is not the right tool. There is zero guarantee from Postgres that a notification gets delivered

Comment: You are saying pg_notify is not the right way to strive for reliability ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, no problem. Write a process that listens on all available channels and writes every notification it gets into a log file. Then you know which notifications were sent. If any client did not react to an event, the client was either not connected at the time or ignored the message.

Comment: Does postgre have such log file by default in which I could just read ?

Comment: No, it doesn't.